# Maven repository in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm new to Maven and Nexus. I have already .m2 folder and it includes all of needed libraries with their pom, and working nexus. I'm trying to make new Nexus and use this nexus instead of working nexus. After that my maven should download dependencies from new nexus. How do I deploy all of the folders in the .m2 from working nexus to new nexus. I don't now old nexus how installed and configured. The reason that download from new nexus is my working environment is offline.I looked up some questions but couldn't find exact answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.m2` isn't a Nexus repository. That's where a user's local repository is kept. Nexus keeps its files in a `sonatype-work` directory by default. Generally speaking, you can just copy this directory from one Nexus installation to another, and it'll work fine.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, I didn't thought like that, I was trying to install them via maven. Actually it is very simple, thanks again..